# PowerShell Invoke-Command Argumentlist

Tags: powershell, arguments

I'm struggling to pass my arguments to my custom made function.

This works fine:

```powershell
Delete-OldFiles -Target $Target -OlderThanDays $OlderThanDays -LogName Auto_Clean.log
```

These don't work at all:

```powershell
# (using -ScriptBlock ${Function:Delete-OldFiles} for all calls)

Invoke-Command -ArgumentList ( ".$Target", ".$OlderThanDays", ".$LogName Auto_Clean.log")

Invoke-Command -ArgumentList @("$Target", "$OlderThanDays", "Auto_Clean.log") 

Invoke-Command -ArgumentList @({-OlderThanDays "10", -Target "E:\Share\Dir1", -LogName "Auto_Clean.log"})

Invoke-Command -ArgumentList (,@('$Target','$OlderThanDays','Auto_Clean.log'))
```

Can you help me on how to pass the following parameters correctly:

```powershell
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
    [String]$Server,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [String]$Target,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=3)]
    [Int]$OlderThanDays,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=4)]
    [String]$LogName,
    [switch]$CleanFolders
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Invoke-Command -ArgumentList` arguments are passed to script block as positional parameters. Looking at you `param()` block: it was not designed with using positional parameters in mind... Having optional parameters first, and mandatory after means you always need to provide optional parameter, or use named parameters for all mandatory ones.

In other words: having optional parameter in the first position will stop you from running this code in this fashion with `Invoke-Command`.

To test your code locally you should try it this way:

```
Delete-OldFiles $Target $OlderThanDays "Auto_Clean.log"
```

I would expect it to prompt you for `LogName` parameter.

Comment: Thank you BartekB, I finally see it now. I changed the order of my parameters to have the `$Server`mentioned last and now it works fine. Thanks again man! I was really looking hard on this one...